# Is it possible to access Open Graph Insights via Graph API or other programmatic means?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-insights

I'm able to access FQL Insights metrics (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/) such as "application_active_users" for my App via the Graph API;  however, the Open Graph Insights metrics (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/insights/) such as "published actions" and "ticker impressions" don't seem to be available via Graph API.  I looked through the documentation thoroughly and don't see this addressed.  Has anyone been able to access Open Graph Insights programmatically?

Comment: have you claimed your domain for the app your using? 
https://www.facebook.com/insights

Answer (score 0):

My impression is, these metrics are combined for us, and there is no way to access the individual metric.

referring to: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/

**page_impressions_organic**
The number of times your posts were seen in News Feed or Ticker or on visits to your Page. These impressions can be Fans or non-Fans

**page_impressions_organic_unique** 
The number of people who visited your Page, or saw your Page or one of its posts in News Feed or Ticker. These impressions can be Fans or non-Fans

**page_posts_impressions_organic**
The number of impressions of your posts in News Feed or Ticker or on your Page  day, week, days_28

**page_posts_impressions_organic_unique**
The number of people who saw your Page posts in News Feed or Ticker, or on your Page's Wall

**post_impressions_organic***
The number of impressions of your post in Newsfeed, Ticker, or on your Page's Wall

**post_impressions_organic_unique***
The number of people who saw your post in their Newsfeed or Ticker or on your Page's Wall

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing FQL through the graph api:

http://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=[your insights query]

Answer (score 0):

we can filter the campaign based on the number of impression got by adding parameter in the request body the "filtering" -for that the specify the fields for the filtering in this case it will be impression, next is "oprerator" oprerator is the boolean operator here it is "GREATER_THAN",next is value it will be a number .